# How to exclude selected text and extract the next text separated with " : "?

Tags: vb.net

i'm in the making of machine readable dictionary for my native language which is Malay. i need to extract the Malay translation from the .txt file. In the .txt file, the example are like this:

aberration : aberasi

aberration function : rangkap aberasi

ablation : ablasi

ablative material : bahan ablasi

the left one are the terms in English and after the separator : is Malay.
What I would like to ask is how do i do when the word search is "aberration function" and i need to display only "rangkap aberasi"?

i tried to used

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim text As String = "dictionary.txt"
        Dim word As String = "\b" & TextBox2.Text & "\b\s+(\w+)"

        For Each a As Match In Regex.Matches(text, word, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

            MsgBox(a.Groups(1).Value)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

See more at: http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/get-the-next-word-after-a-specific-word-in-visual-basic.htm#sthash.w8E1Qb6l.dpuf

however, my problem is, this code above only display the next word after seperation which is "rangkap". while i need the whole text after separation ":" which might be more than 2 words.

here is my current code

```
Using reader As New StreamReader("D:\Dictionary of Engineering A only.txt")
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        If line.Contains(wordsearch.Text) Then
            Edef.Text = line
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this would be like this:

```
Using reader As New StreamReader("D:\Dictionary of Engineering A only.txt")
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        If line.Contains(wordsearch.Text) Then
            dim lineParts() as String = line.split(":")
            Edef.Text = lineParts(1)
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

You check if the line contains the text, if so, you split the line by the ":" and take the 2nd part of it.